# What's the purpose of parentheses around function name in Javascript code?

Tags: javascript

I saw a piece of javascript code similar to the one below. I understand the `eval()` function but don't understand the purpose of the first pair of parenthesis around the function name and another parameter. Thank you for the help.

```
(1,eval)("function Func() {}")
```

Comment: Where have you seen the code. `(1,eval)` is an expression which will return `eval` because comma operator returns last expression of all the expression which are separated.

Comment: @MaheerAli I think the purpose is to remove the implicit `window` calling context